# Visual Studio Database Deployment Including Tables From Another Project

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, deployment

Morning All,

I'm having an issue where Visual Studio is including tables from another database project within the same solution (that is referenced) as part of the deployment of another database.

So Database A references Database B but when JUST deploying database A tables from Database B are included within the deployment script

Any ideas?

(VS2017)

Comment: If you don't deploy the Database B tables, wouldn't the references to those from Database A be invalid?

Comment: 1 table is referenced for a SP in Database A, that's it... so why include all tables from database B? Just to add Database C is also referenced in Database A but tables from that project aren't deployed